# Django complete form as signed up user

Tags: html, django, forms, django-views, django-forms

After you sign up, you are prompted to a page that contains a form used for gathering additional information about the new user and after that it redirects you to the login page. The problem is that the form doesn't submit if i don't specify the {{form.user}} instance in the html file. Probably because the user_id is not recognized by default. When i specify it, the form let me chooses from already existing users, and i would like it to go with the logged in user by default.

views.py

```
class CreateInfoView(CreateView):
    model = AdditionalInfoModel

    form_class = AdditionallnfoModelForm
    template_name = "user_ski_experience/additional_info.html"

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        variable_to_send = super(CreateInfoView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        variable_to_send.update({'pk': None})
        variable_to_send.update({'pk_user': self.request.user.pk})
        return variable_to_send

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.created_by = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('login')
```

forms.py

```
class AdditionallnfoModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = AdditionalInfoModel
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, pk,  *args, **kwargs):
        pk_user = kwargs.pop('pk_user')
        super(AdditionallnfoModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.pk = pk

        self.fields['user'].disabled = True
        self.fields['user'].initial = pk_user
    
        for el in self.fields:
            self.fields[el].label = False

    def clean(self):
        return self.cleaned_data
```

How can i solve this ?

Comment: So the flow is *Sign up -> Add extra info -> Login*? How can you add the logged in user as the default if the user hasn't logged in yet. Or I got something wrong?

Comment: No. The Flow is Sign-up -> Login -> Add extra info. I want that if an user has already completed the form, to bypass the add info page and get redirected to the home page

Comment: Please share the `AdditionalInfoModel`? It looks like you have a `user` and a `created_by` field?

Answer (score 0):

```
class AdditionalInfoModel(models.Model):
    objects = None
    skill_choices = (('Beginner', 'BEGINNER'),
                    ('Intermediate', 'INTERMEDIATE'),
                    ('Expert', 'EXPERT'))

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    assumed_technical_ski_level = models.CharField(max_length=30, 
    choices=skill_choices)
    years_of_experience = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True)
    money_to_spend = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True)
    resort_choice = models.ForeignKey(Resorts, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
    blank = True, null = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).